# bigo live not working on fedora

Tags: linux

On my fedora linux I am unable to play bigo.tv streams. It shows mobile view window and when I click on play bigo icon keeps loading. I tried on firefox, chrome both.

[image]

Comment: Open browsers' deverloper tools, search the console, find red lines with error messages, they probably write error messages there.

Comment: just checked...only some error for analytics...and this should be no reason to restrict browser to load mobile version instead of desktop version...

Comment: I think sometimes might show destkop browsers their mobile version if the window's not maximized, if the minimized window is not very big. Sometimes if it's very small. Trying to maximize the browser window would be a must do step.

Comment: I guess you probably have tried that already.

Comment: yeah...tried with not only maximize I tried with resizing screen, browser screen....no luck with it....on tor browser desktop version shows but it do not support flash so stream do not work in tor....